# mysql import csv broken encoding

Tags: mysql

I try to import a csv file into mysql table. Everything is fine except encoding - in my resulting table I see

```
ÐÐ½Ñ‚Ð¸Ð¾Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ´ÐµÐ»Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒ Ð½Ð¾Ð¼ÐµÑ€Ð°
```

except normal text. During import dialog I choose UTF-8, no other encodings are accepted.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Thank you

Comment: That doesn't look "fine" at all. Make sure your input is in UTF-8 format. If it isn't, convert it.

Comment: My input is a txt file which I edit in Notepad. When I save my file there I choose UTF-8, but this does not help(( If I choose some other encodings, import process breaks with error. With UTF8 no errors are displayed, but the text encoding is wrong